# Printing to a txt file in columns of ten?

Tags: c, output, text-files

So far, I can print in one column quite nicely :

```
for (i = 0 ; i < *lengthOfFile ; i++)
{   
    fprintf(myFile, "%d\n", thisArray[i]);
}
```

Easy enough.  However, how would I go about printing in columns of ten if say I have 20 or 100 or 10000 or more numbers?

Anything would help very much, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print "%d\t" instead of "%d\n", and move the "\n" into its own print statement that only occurs when (i % 10) == 0.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I tried with and without the '\t' to see the difference and man, the '\t' makes it so much neater.  What, exactly, does the \t do?

Comment: the '\t' is a short hand in C for the tab character.

Answer (score 1):

loop by tens instead of by ones. Check if you are not over the size. Mind the "punctuation" (newlines, tabs, commas, ...).

```
for (i = 0 ; i < *lengthOfFile ; i += 10)
{   
    fprintf(myFile, "%d", thisArray[i]);
    for (k = 1; k < 10; k++) {
        if (i + k < *lengthOfFile) fprintf(myFile, "\t%d", thisArray[i + k]);
    }
    fprintf(myFile, "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could for example use the `%8d` format to print (it will write every number so that it takes 8 characters) and then every ten iterations, print a new line character (if you want 10 columns).

Answer (score 1):

Extending [*trooper*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/975741/trooper)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26574925/694576):

```
#define MAXIMUM_COLUMNS (10) 

for (i = 0; i < *lengthOfFile; ++i)
{   
  fprintf(myFile, "%d%c", thisArray[i], (i % MAXIMUM_COLUMNS) ?'\t' :'\n');
}
```